# apollo-link-state complains when call cache.writeData

Tags: apollo

I am new to apollo-link-state, and am stuck for a while. My problem to solve is simple, just save a modal information into local state, however, when I try to save into, it complains:

```
ApolloError.js?f55daa5:36 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Cannot read property 'selections' of null
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js?f55daa5:36)
    at Object.error (QueryManager.js?8f5ff47:115)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (zen-observable.js?8f5ff47:176)
    at <anonymous>
```

My source code, likes like below:

```
{ // resolvers and defaults
  resolvers: {
    Mutation: {
      openModal: (_, args, { cache }) => {
        const {name} = args
        cache.writeData({
          modal: {
            name,
            open: true,
            __typename: 'Modal',
          },
        })
        return null
      },
      closeModal: (_, __, {cache}) => {
        cache.writeData({modal: {open: false}})
      }
    }
  },
  defaults: {
    modal: {
      __typename: 'Modal',
      open: false,
      name: ''
    }
  }
}

graphql(
    gql`
        mutation openModal  ($name: String!) {
            openModal  (name: $name) @client
        }
    `
  )(
  ({mutate}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => mutate({ variables: { name: 'test' }})} >Open</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
)
```

When clicking the button, the error message comes. Any thoughts?

By the way, I am using in next.js.

Comment: I created a bug in `apollo-link-state repo`, see: [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/issues/172)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. After referencing the code from [the todos example](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/blob/master/examples/todo/src/resolvers/visibilityFilter.js#L8) I found out that you have to wrap your object like this `{ data: { // your actual data } }`. So in your case, it may be:

```
cache.writeData({
  data: {
    modal: {
      name,
      open: true,
      __typename: 'Modal',
    },
  },
});
```